# How to call a function after main window function is called or loaded in WPF C# Application

Tags: c#, wpf

In my wpf application, there is a function which fetches string values from a file and loads in textboxes.

I could not able to figure out how to call a function after main window function of MainWindow.xaml.cs file is called.

(Note: The question previously, was how to count height of textboxes from main window function. These textboxes are created in the main window itself. But didnot get solution, so modified the question)

Comment: I have a great solution for you: **don't** insert any `TextBox`es in the code-behind. Instead, use the powerful data templating mechanism. With that, you won't need to calculate any UI elements sizes. Creating UI in code is not how WPF was intended to work with.

Comment: Dynamoid is right. [Have a look there](https://wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/introduction/)

Comment: Is the size of your `Textbox` the same as the `FontSize`of the `TextBox`?

Answer (score 0):

The height of the textbox doesn't change automatcialy with `TextWrapping.Wrap` the text is just kinda hidden, you can see it with this example

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    test.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
    test.Text = "hey let's write some text that will go over the limit";
}
```

test is a TextBox

Answer (score 0):

Your `TextBox` size will not be having the correct *size* unless it's rendered completely. Try checking the `ActualHeight` or `ActualWidth` in a `Button` click after it got rendered.

You can also refer [`UpdateLayout()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.updatelayout?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_UIElement_UpdateLayout), if you want to do it before it's rendered.